# Faulting application splwow64.exe

Tags: c++, vmware

I am running Windows 7 64 pro. When I start VMware player, with Windows XP service pack 3 installed, I get the error message "this application has requested runtime to terminate it in an unusual way" Microsoft visual C++.

I have dug into the event log and it is telling me that splwow64.exe is the faulting application. I was concerned at first but now that I know that it is a 32 bit print spooler it does not seem like such a big deal but it is annoying. Any thoughts on how to correct the problem?

Answer (score 0):

splwow64 has issues with vmware (leaks memory). Remove printers from the guest machine on vmware, should work normally.

Comment: Thanks Marin It is a work computer so removing the printers is not an option. I haven't quite managed to go completely paperless yet. Ed

Comment: If it is a work computer, why use virtual machine for work then? You can leave the printers on your computer, just remove them from the operating system on virtual machine. Or do you have some old SW that doesn't work on Win7?